# Elasticsearch 6.3.0 jarhell module-info.class

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lombok

Hi i'm using Spring Boot 2, Lombok and Elasticsearch 6.3.0 in my project and try to run my integration test but run into the infamous jar hell! check.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
class: module-info
jar1: home/tim/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.22/lombok 
1.16.22.jar
jar2: /home/tim/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-
api/2.10.0/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkClass(JarHell.java:273)
  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:190)
  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:86)
  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:93)
```

`module-info.class` is present in both lombok and log4j-api (transive dependency of elasticsearch). I can't exclude log4j-api because Elasticsearch requires this class but don't want to remove lombok because it helps me to avoid writing boilerplate Java code.

Any clue how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I suggest using [embedded-elasticsearch](https://github.com/allegro/embedded-elasticsearch) to run Elasticsearch in a separate process. Your project's dependencies will not be included in the process running Elasticsearch.

Comment: Chin Huang, embedded Elasticsearch is not a thing any more since 5.0. The dependency problem should be coming from the client that has an Elasticsearch dependency. @jtim can you post your dependency? High level REST client or Transport client (maybe even through Spring Data)?

Comment: I've been having JarHell trouble, too. I downgraded the log4j-api and log4j-core versions to 2.7 and JarHell is gone (for now)

Comment: @xeraa I'm using the elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client version 6.3.0.
Downgrading is a work around that can work. I'll create a ticket in the Elasticsearch issue tracker because i think more people will hit similar issues.

Comment: Could you share a link to the issue? I'm hitting this issue as well and would like to follow any progress made on fixing it.

Comment: I couldn't find the ticket you were referring to, so I created my own: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/32985

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I was in the process of creating a sample project and ticket but something else came in between. Thanks for creating a ticket i'll monitor it.